# EF Core generates incorrect character for an UTF-8 string when running PostgreSQL query

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework-core

My problem is when I try to put a value to method .Where with type is utf-8 but value generate is normal text.

```
query = query.Where(x => x.DisplayName != null && x.DisplayName.ToLower().Contains(slowUsername));
```

slowUsername is has value : ***"nghĩa"*** . But the result when generate to query is ***"nghia"***

[image]

Comment: No it doesn't and your very question just proved it. .NET strings are natively Unicode and StackOverflow is an ASP.ENT Core application. .NET never had any issues with Unicode or UTF8. How did you determine there's a problem to begin with? Where did you check the string? Are you sure the problem isn't your *console*?

Comment: BTW post the output as *text*, not images of the text. Images can't be copied, compiled, googled or checked for invisible characters. Although, if what you claimed was true you wouldn't see `nghia` at all, you'd see two mangled characters. Perhaps the console normalized the string during display? Perhaps *your* code did the same? Perhaps the database field has the wrong collation, resulting in normalization?  That `x.DisplayName.ToLower().Contains(slowUsername)` is certainly an *ugly* smell, a perf bu and possibly what caused the problem here.

Comment: `x.DisplayName.ToLower().Contains(slowUsername)` *prevents* the database from using any indexes on `DisplayName`. If your field uses case-*in*sensitive collation, this will force a full table scan for no reason. This will scan eg 1M rows instead of just 1. During paging your code will scan all rows every time. If you want to perform case-*in*sensitives create an index on the expression `lower(DisplayName)`